# Is there a way to update a nested attribute in DynamoDB using DynamoDB Mapper

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-mapper

I have a DynamoDB Schema with nested attributes. Hence lets say below is my mapper structure.

```
public class Test
{
@DynamoDBHashKey private String testPk;
@DynamoDBRangeKey private String testSk;
@DynamoDBAttribute private String name;
@DynamoDBAttribute private MyClass myClass;
}

@DynamoDBDocument
public class MyClass{
@DynamoDBAttribute private String myName;
@DynamoDBAttribute private String mySubject;
}
```

Now this would lead to a schema like:

```
{
"testPk":<value>,
"testSk":<value,
"name":<value>,
"myClass":{
      "myName":<value>,
      "mySubject":<value>
   }
}
```

I am using a Dynamo DB Mapper to update this object. The dynamo DB Mapper config is as follows:

```
 DynamoDBMapperConfig.builder() .withSaveBehavior(DynamoDBMapperConfig.SaveBehavior.UPDATE_SKIP_NULL_ATTRIBUTES) .withConsistentReads(DynamoDBMapperConfig.ConsistentReads.EVENTUAL) .build();
```

**This is done so that fields that are null/not updated are ignored by the save operation.**

**However as per my observation, this configuration is only working for the primitive Data Types in the "Test" class and not for the custom DynamoDBDocument(MyClass) defined in the mapper(Test.java). Whenever I am trying to update the MyClass object, if I try to change only "myName", "mySubject" gets set to null which overrides its older value which means "update_skip_null_attributes" is not working on the DynamoDBDocument.**

How can I change this update behavior on the nested json.?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, did you find any solution for this?